# What is the largest $k$ such that $ \frac { k(abc) }{ a+b+c } \le \left( a+b \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( a+b+4c \right) ^{ 2 } $?

Tags: inequality

> Find the largest value of $ k $ such that
>
> $$k \cdot \left(\frac { abc }{ a+b+c }\right) \le \left( a+b \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( a+b+4c \right) ^{ 2 }$$

Comment: Not even a *please*?

Comment: is this really level 5?

Comment: Also, what kind of variables do we have?

Comment: Are the values poditive real numbers, otherwise we can take one of teh values as zero and the left becomes zero.

Answer (score 7):

if $a,b,c>0$,I have answer $k\le 100$

since Use AM-GM inequality we have
\begin{align*}(a+b)^2+(a+b+4c)^2&=(a+b)^2+[(a+2c)+(b+2c)]^2\ge (2\sqrt{ab})^2+(2\sqrt{2ac}+2\sqrt{2bc})^2\\
&=4ab+8ac+8bc+16c\sqrt{ab}
\end{align*}
so
$$\dfrac{(a+b)^2+(a+b+4c)^2}{abc}\ge8\left(\dfrac{1}{2c}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ab}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ab}}\right)$$
$$a+b+c=\dfrac{a}{2}+\dfrac{a}{2}+\dfrac{b}{2}+\dfrac{b}{2}+c$$
so use AM-GM inequality we have
$$\dfrac{(a+b)^2+(a+b+4c)^2}{abc}(a+b+c)\ge 8\left(5\sqrt[5]{\dfrac{1}{2a^2b^2c}}\right)
\left(5\sqrt[5]{\dfrac{a^2b^2c}{2^4}}\right)=100$$
if and only if
$a=b=2c$

Comment: This answer assumes that $a,b,c>0$.

Answer (score 0):

If the variables are real numbers take $c=0$ and the left becomes zero no matter what $k$ we choose, so the values for $k$ are all of $\mathbb R$.

---

If the variables are positive real numbers we multiply both sides by $a+b+c$, and expand to get:

$k(abc)\leq2a^3+2b^3+16c^3+6b^2a+6a^2b+10a^2c+10b^2c+24c^2a+24c^2b$

fix, $c$ and $b$ as $1$ and we get:

$ka\leq 2a^3+2+16+6a+6a^2+10a^2+10+24a+24$

The important thing here is the right is larger than $a^2$.

So we get $ka\leq a^2\iff k\leq a$. So for sufficiently large $a$ we can take on any positive real $k$.

When the values are integers the same method applies.